# Firebase database structuring

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

We are working on a mobile app and there are primarily 5 objects added. how should we reference to Other objects data? should we use some id or should full path. What if we dont make duplicate data and use only one reference to update/delete. will it kill the performance? what is the best way to create DB structure for millions of records?

Comment: your question is too broad to answer, you'll have to share the structure that you are planning to create, their associations, data access and retrieval scenarios.

Comment: take a look at this series of short videos from Firebase guys (2nd one in particular might address your question) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s